# How to create a dependency on an external program?

Tags: gnu-make

Is it possible to create a dependency on a program outside of the project? e.g. I'm trying

```
composer: /usr/local/bin/composer
    sudo wget --no-check-certificate https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar -O /usr/local/bin/composer && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

But when I set this as a dependency for another target it always runs even though the file is there.

Comment: That's because you have told _make_ how to build `composer`. _Make_ dutifully carries out your instructions, creating `/usr/local/bin/composer` as a _side effect_. You will note that `composer` is not created by your recipe, so _make_ wil ltry to create it the next time you run!

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this works:

```
COMPOSER_BIN = $(shell command -v composer || command -v /usr/bin/composer || echo "___composer___")

$(COMPOSER_BIN):
    sudo wget --no-check-certificate https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar --output-document /usr/local/bin/composer && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I'm just not sure about the fallback command...